# Stripe subscription best practice for cancel and reactivate model

Tags: paypal, stripe-payments, payment, subscription, subscriptions

I'm working on an app have a monthly subscription plan form Stripe.
I'm creating a customer then subscription for users to subscribe which is working fine for me but I have not figure out how to create cancelation flow with Stripe subscription.

I used a cancel subscription button with `stripe.subscriptions.del` and it gives me a problem in a situation when that user wants to reactivate subscription. What is the best practice to make cancel subscription flow?

1. user clicks cancel subscription button
2. execute `stripe.subscriptions.del` to cancel current subscription but keep the user's customer ID
3. when user reactivate the subscription, create a new subscription to the existing customer ID with `stripe.subscriptions.create`

Does it make sense? or there's better ways to implement this?

Comment: If a subscription marked as canceled. There is no way to re activated. A new one can only be achieved. According to Stripe docs. https://prnt.sc/q9xgxm

Comment: If you want to give user a way to reactivate the subscription you need to update it to {cancel_at_period_end: true} so you can update this params to false for reactivating: https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/cancel