# In Stripe, best practice for re-activating a canceled subscription

Tags: stripe-payments

[Stripe subscription best practice for cancel and reactivate model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43484325/stripe-subscription-best-practice-for-cancel-and-reactivate-model) - my question is similar to this question from 6 years ago that unfortunately went unanswered. Stripe makes it pretty clear in [their docs](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/cancel#reactivating-canceled-subscriptions) that cancelled subscriptions cannot be restarted. However, we'd like users to be able to cancel and renew their subscription. Is the best pattern to:

- cancel, and create a brand new subscription when the user tries to re-activate their account?
- do not technically cancel. rather, change the status to some `active but paused / not collecting payments` status, that way it can be re-activated if a user chooses to do so?
- unknown other option

What is the best practice here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think how you choose to handle the cancellation ultimately depends on how you want to deliver services. You could cancel a subscription immediately; this changes the subscription status to `canceled` and is a terminal state. You could update a subscription so it is canceled at the end of the current billing period; this means the subscription will remain `active` until the end of the current period and you can continue to make changes to the subscription until then.

If a user tries to reactivate once the subscription is `canceled`, you should create a brand-new subscription. While there is a ["pause" option](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/pause), pausing still generates invoices; Stripe calls out that this may affect your accounting data.

Comment: `You could update a subscription so it is canceled at the end of the current billing period; this means the subscription will remain active until the end of the current period and you can continue to make changes to the subscription until then.` - this is what we do currently, and users can switch back and forth in this state before terminal cancellation.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation to create a brand-new subscription, it seems this is our best option barring an alternative I am missing. We probably don't want invoices created for cancelled accounts.